# c++: do we need to explicitly specify type info for template function, when using NULL/nullptr?

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameters, nullptr

I've got this template function:

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T* t1, const T* t2) {}
```

Then in main():

```
    int i = 1;
    f(&i, NULL);
```

It doesn't compile, saying `candidate template ignored: could not match 'const T *' against 'int'`

If change it into:

```
    int i = 1;
    f(&i, nullptr); // same error!
```

I know I can fix it like this, specifying the type info:

```
    int i = 1;
    f<int>(&i, NULL);
```

Ok, it gets compiled.

But isn't it that, c++ compiler could do type deduction for us : so that we can call template functions without specifying all the type information?

Seems `NULL`/`nullptr` here is an unusual case for template.

My question: is there a way to go without `f<int>` in each place, just `f`, when there's `NULL`/`nullptr`?

Thanks.

Comment: `{}` or `{nullptr}` or `{NULL}` instead of `nullptr` or `NULL` would work without changing the function. Using braced arguments makes the argument/parameter pair automatically a non-deduced context. You are basically saying that you don't want this argument to be used for deduction.

Comment: `int i = 1; int* null_int = nullptr; f(&i, null_int);`

Comment: A default argument (`void f(const T* t1, const T* t2 = nullptr)`) would also work if you want to write `f(&i)` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler uses both parameter to deduce `T`, and because neither `nullptr` nor `NULL` are of type `int*` there is a conflict between the types deduced from `&i` and from `nullptr` / `NULL`.

Note that `nullptr` is of type `nullptr_t`. It can be converted to any other pointer type, but `nullptr_t` is a distinct type.

Since C++20 you can use [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) to establish a non-deduced context:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void f(const T* t1, const std::type_identity_t<T>* t2) {}

int main() {
    const int* x;
    f(x,nullptr);  // calls f<int>
}
```

The second parameter will then not be used to deduce `T`. Whether this is really what you want depends on details of `f`. Before C++20, the trait is rather simple to write yourself (see possible implementation).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, "establish a non-deduced context" is so well explained: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts, I've learned it.

Answer (score 1):

```
do we need to explicitly specify type info for template function, when using NULL/nullptr
```

To know the answer, we need to know the type of the variable/function/macro being used for.
Hence when facing any error or warning during compilation,

```
f(&i, nullptr); // same error!
```

learn gdb/dbx/gdb.exe to know the type of the variable or function using

```
ptype variable_name
ptype function_name
```

Once known, we can add related type casting to remove that error and warning.
When "ptype variable_name" not working,
Search related macro/function using related header/c/C++ file.

I thought of sharing my comment.
Like the way of your polymorphism using multiple comments :) at stackoverflow.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
// FIRST PARAMETER AND SECOND PARAMETER NEEDS TO BE A POINTER USING SAME TYPE const T*
void f(const T* t1, const T* t2)
{
    return;
}
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    f( &i, (int*)NULL );
    f<int>( &i, NULL );
    // f( &i, NULL );   // PASSING int* and char*
    float f1 = 20.22;
    f<float>( &f1, NULL);
    return 0;
}
/* g++.exe -Wall -g 73526963.cpp -o ./a.out
 * OR
 * g++     -Wall -g 73526963.cpp -o ./a.out
 * LEARN debugging using gdb/dbx/gdb.exe based on your operating system.
 * Know the prototype of the function and polymorphism using ptype/where for parameters inside gdb.
$ gdb ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x10040108d: file 73526963.cpp, line 11.
(gdb) run
Starting program: ./a.out
[New Thread 936.0x474]
[New Thread 936.0x634]
[New Thread 936.0x480]
[New Thread 936.0x2578]

Thread 1 "a.out" hit Breakpoint 1, main () at 73526963.cpp:11
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
11              int i = 1;
(gdb) next
12              f( &i, (int*)NULL );
(gdb) step
f<int> (t1=0xffffcbec, t2=0x0) at 73526963.cpp:7
7               return;
(gdb) ptype t1
type = const int *
(gdb) ptype t2
type = const int *
(gdb) next
8       }
(gdb)
main () at 73526963.cpp:13
13              f<int>( &i, NULL );
(gdb) step
f<int> (t1=0xffffcbec, t2=0x0) at 73526963.cpp:7
7               return;
(gdb) ptype t1
type = const int *
(gdb) ptype t2
type = const int *
(gdb) next
8       }
(gdb)
main () at 73526963.cpp:15
15              float f1 = 20.22;
(gdb)
16              f<float>( &f1, NULL);
(gdb) step
f<float> (t1=0xffffcbe8, t2=0x0) at 73526963.cpp:7
7               return;
(gdb) ptype t1
type = const float *
(gdb) ptype t2
type = const float *
(gdb) next
8       }
(gdb)
main () at 73526963.cpp:17
17              return 0;
(gdb)
18      }
(gdb)
0x0000000180049b7d in _cygwin_exit_return () from /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll
(gdb)
Single stepping until exit from function _cygwin_exit_return,
which has no line number information.
[Thread 936.0x480 exited with code 0]
[Thread 936.0x474 exited with code 0]
[Thread 936.0x2024 exited with code 0]
[Thread 936.0x634 exited with code 0]
[Inferior 1 (process 936) exited normally]
(gdb) quit
$ # We can use b/break or stop in or stop at or step or s or next or n or continue or c based on related available debugger at current OS.
*/
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32604533)

Comment: Updated my comments.